# How to prove $(a+b)^n\leq (1+\epsilon(2^{n-1}-1))a^n+(1+\frac{2^{n-1}-1}{\epsilon^{n-1}})b^n$ for $\epsilon\in(0,1)$

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove the inequality $(a+b)^n\leq (1+\epsilon(2^{n-1}-1))a^n+(1+\frac{2^{n-1}-1}{\epsilon^{n-1}})b^n$ for $\epsilon\in(0,1)$. It is not that straight forward to me. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to math SE! Your question is easier to answer if you [provide some context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Comment: An interesting question. But a poor question. Is this just an assigned homework question? I'd be sad if this inequality didn't come with a backstory.

Comment: Thanks! It is a part of the paper I was reading: Error expansion for the discretization of backward stochastic differential equations by Gobet & Labart, page 8. [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602503.pdf)@MaximilianJanisch

Comment: Thanks! It is a part of the paper I was reading: Error expansion for the discretization of backward stochastic differential equations by Gobet & Labart, page 8. [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602503.pdf)@RobertWolfe

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

- Consider the r.h.s of the inequality as a function of $\epsilon$, say $g_n(\epsilon)$.
- Prove that for all $n>1$, the function $g_n(\epsilon)$ decreases in $(0,1]$.
- Prove that $(a+b)^n<g_n(1)$,

and deduce your inequality.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! However, it is not sufficient to show that g is decreasing.

Comment: Why would you think so ?